# Parted: Creating partitions on a drive for EUFI boot, fat16 doesn't mount properly or show up on firmware as boot option

Tags: uefi, boot-loader, parted, fat

I have a library (referred to here as "wic") that generates a `drive.img` file that contains multiple partitions, including a boot partition with a UFI exe. If I `dd if=drive.img of=/dev/sdb`, it works perfectly.

I am referring wic to make another script that will create the same partitions directly on the drive, instead of an intermediate `drive.img`.

In my script, the boot partition contains the exact files/structure that the original library produced, bit-for-bit. I referred to wic to determine the exact `parted` commands to call.

The problem is that the EFI exe isn't detected on boot using my script.

I noticed some differences between the drive I create, vs the drive that wic makes (after `dd if=drive.img of=/dev/sdb`) that may help determine what I am doing wrong.

- If I previously flash a drive with wic and then use my script to recreate the partitions, it works fine. However, after a few times running my script, it will stop working and the drive will start to behave weirdly.
- `parted` doesn't recognize the file system type for the fat partition.
- When my script isn't working, when mounting `/dev/sdb1`, it will use a loopback device.

Output:

```
sdb           8:64   1    15G  0 disk
├─sdb1        8:65   1   1.5G  0 part
├─sdb2        8:66   1    12G  0 part
└─sdb3        8:67   1   1.5G  0 part
loop0         7:3    0  16.6M  0 loop  /media/pknopf/efi
loop1         7:4    0  16.6M  0 loop  /media/pknopf/efi1
```

When I mount this partition after using wic, the partition get's mounted properly, without loopback.

Here is my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DEVICE="/dev/sdb"
# This is a fat filesystem that contains grub EFI and grub.cfg.
BOOTIMG="/boot.img"

parted -s $DEVICE mklabel gpt
parted -a optimal $DEVICE mkpart primary fat16 0% 10%
parted -a optimal $DEVICE mkpart primary ext2 10% 90%
parted -a optimal $DEVICE mkpart primary ext2 90% 100%

sgdisk --partition-guid=1:3948166f-7d1b-4b75-ad77-5ed5ad5f8e37 $DEVICE
sgdisk --partition-guid=2:9d69c3d4-4175-4a46-baba-64f95bcea861 $DEVICE
sgdisk --partition-guid=3:79067919-3db0-4c63-b78e-b72ce880cd42 $DEVICE

parted $DEVICE name 1 msdos
parted $DEVICE name 2 medxplatform
parted $DEVICE name 3 data

sync

# Boot partition
parted $DEVICE set 1 esp on
# $BOOTIMG is a pre-made fat img using mkdosfs
dd if=$BOOTIMG of=${DEVICE}1 

# Rootfs partition
mkfs.ext4 ${DEVICE}2 -F -L medxplatform

# Data partition
mkfs.ext4 ${DEVICE}3 -F -L data
```

**EDIT**: It seems that `parted` doesn't see the file system type when using my script, but it sees it when using wic.

My script:

```
Model: innostor USB 3.0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 16.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name          Flags
 1      1049kB  1611MB  1610MB               msdos         legacy_boot, msftdata
 2      1611MB  14.5GB  12.9GB  ext4         medxplatform
 3      14.5GB  16.1GB  1610MB  ext4         data
```

Wic:

```
Model: innostor USB 3.0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 16.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name          Flags
 1      1049kB  25.7MB  24.7MB  fat16        msdos         legacy_boot, msftdata
 2      26.2MB  10.5GB  10.5GB  ext4         medxplatform
 3      10.5GB  11.6GB  1074MB  ext4         data
```

Note, I'm aware the partition sizes are different, but I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Cross posted to reddit here: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/8jmhgl/parted_creating_partitions_on_a_drive_for_eufi/

Comment: Have you tried using `mkdosfs` on the partition instead of `dd`-ing an image? It shouldn't make a difference, but who knows.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I have, same result.

Comment: Have you marked the fat16 partition as the ESP?, Since that's where your UEFI executables are, marking the partition as the ESP tells your UEFI firmware where to look. The command would be something like `parted $DEVICE set 1 esp on`

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, yup, no luck. Something tells me that the weird mounting behavior is an extension of a deeper issue with the file system/drive. I've tried multiple drives, same issue.

Comment: Here is the drive with the esp/boot set. My motherboard still doesn't see it. https://pastebin.com/yQVtdNqk

Comment: Have you tried zeroing out the drive before running your script to ensure you start from a clean baseline?

Comment: I also wonder if a size mismatch between the "pre-made" fat16 filesystem and the size of the partition could be an issue.

Comment: @plugwash, funny you ask that. My script works for a few times after I previously run a script that I know works. However,  if I dd /dev/zero to the drive completely, my script fails 100% of the time. There is something my script isn't doing that is needed, that the previous working script does.

Comment: @plugwash, also, I've tried mkdosfs without previous boot.img, no worky.